# Query non-empty values of a row first asc before empty

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have these records in my `fruits` table :

```
id  | name   | order
----|--------|-------
1   | Apple  | 1
2   | Banana | null
3   | Orange | 2
4   | Grapes | null
```

What query should I make so that the result will look like this:

```
id  | name   | order
----|--------|-------
1   | Apple  | 1
3   | Orange | 2
2   | Banana | null
4   | Grapes | null
```

Basically I want those records with non-empty `order` values to be in the top rows, followed by those records with empty `order` arranged alphabetically. How can I accomplish such task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`ISNULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull):

> *If expr is NULL, ISNULL() returns 1, otherwise it returns 0.*

```
SELECT id, name, `order`
FROM fruits
ORDER BY ISNULL(`order`), `order`, name;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ee0f/5/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦═════════╦════════╗
║ id  ║  name   ║ order  ║
╠═════╬═════════╬════════╣
║  1  ║ Apple   ║ 1      ║
║  3  ║ Orange  ║ 2      ║
║  2  ║ Banana  ║ (null) ║
║  4  ║ Grapes  ║ (null) ║
╚═════╩═════════╩════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know I can use `ISNULL` in ordering

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, name, `order`
FROM mytable
ORDER BY IF(`order` IS NULL, 2, 1), 
         `order`,
         name
```

The `IF` conditional will effectively place `NULL` values at the end of the result set.